# Notepad++ Launch in Chrome feature opening with Chrome Canary

Tags: xml, google-chrome, notepad++

I recently downloaded Chrome Canary. After doing so all of the files that I tried to "launch in Chrome", when using Notepad++, opened in Canary, as oppose to the standard version of chrome I have on my machine. In the program files directory, I found the shortcuts.xml with the following line:

```
<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
```

What can I change in that line for it to open with Chrome as oppose to Chrome Canary.

I tried removing Canary, and this causes the Launch in Chrome feature in N++ to not work at all. I've also tried reinstalling N++ after the fact and that didn't change anything.

Also found this in chrome debug log:

```
[0523/141747:ERROR:client_util.cc(293)] Could not find exported function RelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem on Notepad++, i did the following to resolve this :

- Click "Execute" on the Notepad++ menu

You can now select a program on your computer, look for google chrome (Default : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").

- When you're done selecting, don't execute, but press the "save" button.

Notepad will ask a Name, just type whatever you want, like "Google not canary" and assign a shortcut (you're not forced to assign a sc though).

- Press "OK", you will now find the freshly created "Google not canary" in the "Execute" menu.